# Speed up repeated operation via Caching

Tags: java, google-app-engine, objectify

How does caching works with App Engine? Is it enough just to add the `@Cached` annotation:

```
@Cached
public class MyEntity {
    @Id Long id;
    ...
}
```

However, from Objectify docs:

"Objectify's global cache support prior to v3.1 suffered from synchronization problems under contention. **Do not use it for entities which require transactional integrity**, and you are strongly advised to apply an expiration period to all cache values."

Does it mean that if I have a code that have this form below I should not use it?

```
DAOT.repeatInTransaction(new Transactable() {
        @Override
        public void run(DAOT daot)
        {
                Counter count = daot.ofy().find(Counter.class, COUNTER_ID);
                count.increment();
                daot.ofy().put(count);
        }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Objectify tries as hard as it can to make its global cache support [as transactional as possible](https://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/wiki/IntroductionToObjectify):

> The cache in 3.1 has been rewritten from scratch to provide near-transactional consistency with the datastore.

If your request or task runs right up against the deadline limit, for example, there is a possibility that [a write could make it to the datastore but not update the cache](https://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/wiki/MemcacheStandalone):

> The cache is near-transactional. Under normal operation, the cache will not go out of sync with the datastore, even under heavy contention.
>   The exception to this is DeadlineExceededException at the 30s (10m for tasks) hard deadline. If Google kills your process before the cache update occurs, there's nothing we can do.

Comment: So the problem is with Google's timeout, maybe this can be solved by using AppScale?